# Unable to import .pem file in Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

I want to upload .pem file in Azure Key vault and want to access the secret from ADF.
There are 3 options available:

- Upload it under Keys in Azure Key Vault- But keys are not accessible from ADF
- Upload it from Secrets in Azure Key Vault- It is not allowing to upload .pem file under secret
- Upload it from Certificates n Azure Key Vault - It is saying the file is not in proper format

.pem file format:
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
//values
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

problem is only secrets and Certificates are accessible from ADF.

What can be the issue?

I have created key in Azure key vault but keys are not accessible from ADF

So as a solution I have converted the content to Based64 Encoded string which is working but it is not a good scenario if we want to deploy it in higher environment.

Please suggest what can be done

Comment: Convert the .pem file to a .pfx file using openssl?

Comment: Access it how and for what purpose? It's important to understand the use case to recommend the appropriate solution. Also, have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/store-credentials-in-key-vault?